# Property of a ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ be a ring with unity $I$ and $a$ belongs to $R$. How to prove that the ring is commutative if there exists a unique  $b$ in $R$ such that $ab=I$?

My teacher told me to prove $ba=I$, consider the product $a(ba-I+b)$. But I just want know if there is any another way to prove that the ring is commutative.

Please help.

Comment: There do exist non-commutative division rings, so even the second reading proposed by Edgar will not work.

Comment: I think this proposition has counterexample, for example, ring of quaternions.

Comment: Playing around with quantifiers, maybe we are really in the trivial ring, since there would not be such a $b$ for $0$ otherwise.

Comment: As an aside: Rings such that $ab=1\implies ba=1$ are called [Dedekind finite rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set). The question is essentially establishing that if for all $a$ if $ab=1$ for a unique $b$, then $R$ is Dedekind-finite. I can't immediately cite a source, but I think it is true that in Dedekind-*in* finite rings, it happens that if $b$ is not unique, there are actually *infinitely* many $b$'s such that $ab=1$ (as opposed to just two or three).

Comment: @rschwieb If $a$ has two right inverses, then $a$ is a left zero divisor, so we can look at a problem in Lam's _First Course in Noncommutative Rings_ (Section 1 Ex. 14 p. 23) which states that under the hypothesis that $a$ has no left inverse but has a right inverse, then $a$ has infinitely many right inverses.

Comment: @peoplepower Thanks for remembering where that's at :)

Answer (score 4):

It is true that if $a$ is an element of a unital ring $R$ and there exists a unique $b\in R$ such that $ab= I$, then also $ba=I$.  In this case, $b=a^{-1}$, and $b$ commutes with $a$, but this does not imply that $a$ commutes with everything else, let alone that the ring is commutative.  As Mariano mentioned, there are noncommutative rings in which every element is invertible, and as tetori mentioned, the ring of quaternions gives a specific counterexample.

Your teacher gave you a good hint for showing that $ba=I$. First you can simplify $a(ba-I+b)$, then you can use uniqueness of $b$ to finish.